# How to handle paths with spaces when passing arguments to a Rust CLI program on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust, autocomplete, escaping, windows-terminal

I'm writing a Rust CLI program on Windows that expects the user to pass one or more paths as command-line arguments. The program works fine when the paths don't have spaces, but I'm having trouble handling paths that contain spaces.

Here's a minimal example of my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    dbg!(&args);
}
```

And here's an example command that reproduces the issue:

```
cargo run '.\a folder\'
```

When I run this command, I expect to see the following output:

```
&args = [
    "target\\debug\\my-program.exe",
    ".\\a folder\\",
]
```

However, what I actually get is:

```
&args = [
    "target\\debug\\my-program.exe",
    ".\\a folder\"",
]
```

As you can see, the path is not properly parsed and contains a trailing quote.

I suspect that the issue has to do with how I'm escaping the backslashes in the command, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm using backslashes because I'm working in the Windows terminal and want to take advantage of tab completion.

I tried do a replace:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().map(|arg| arg.replace("\\", "/")).collect();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rust, you're passing a broken path because `cmd` handles escaping weirdly, the proper way to provide that path in `cmd` is `cargo run -- ".\a folder\\"` of course just using `/` as path separator also works on windows and doesn't have that problem. Anyways as this is not related to your program or programming in general this should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead, there is probably already an answer there already.

Comment: Actually it's neither `cmd` nor Rust that interpret the `\"`, it's windows' very own [startup code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

This issue lies somewhere between cmd and rust. Apparently [there's no way to escape `"` in quoted strings in cmd](https://superuser.com/a/962805/595088). Instead of `".\a folder\"`, you can pass `.\a" "folder\`. I believe rust's `std::env::args` sees the raw `".\a folder\"` and tries to normalize it by removing the quotes, but treats `\"` as an escaped quote and ignores the missing trailing quote.

I avoid this by using PowerShell, which has much more intuitive escaping behavior, with `` ` `` as the escape character: `` .\a` folder\ `` and `".\a folder\"` both work. POSIX shells use `\`, so if for some reason you were using Windows paths on a POSIX shell, you'd write `.\\a\ folder\\` or `".\\a folder\\"`.